# Unchecking and simulating a click on checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, code-injection

I am admittedly a super newbie to programming in general. I am trying to design a quick piece of javascript to inject on a website for a class that will both uncheck and simulate a click on a series of checkboxes. This is nothing malicious, the web form we use to download data for use in this class presents way more variables than necessary, and it would be a lot more convenient if we could 'uncheck' all and only check the ones we want. However, simply unchecking the boxes via javascript injection doesn't yield the desired result. A mouse click must be simulated on each box. I have been trying to use the .click() function to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated. My code below fails with an error of:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"

CODE:

```
 var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var i = 0, max = getInputs.length; i < max; i++){
 if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
 getInputs[i].checked = false;
 document.getElementById('shr_SUBJECT=VC' + i).click();
 }
```

**--------EDIT#1--------------**

FYI, this is the website that I am trying to use this on:

http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml

if you search for and open up any of these tables they are huge. It would be awesome if I could easily pare down the variables by 'unchecking' and 'clicking' them all at once via javascript.

**The code at the bottom ALMOST works.**
The problem I am running into now is that it throws an error after the first or second run through the for loop:

```
 "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"
```

I understand that this is because the value it's trying to find doesn't exist? Sometimes on these tables the checkboxes are greyed out/don't exist or are otherwise 'unclickable'. My theory as to why I am getting this error is because in the table/form the 'available' ID's will start around:

```
shr_SUBJECT=VC03 or sh_SUBJECT=VC04
```

and it may then skip to:

```
shr_SUBJECT=VC06 then skip to shr_SUBJECT=VC09 and so on...
```

So if the for loop hits an ID that isn't available such as 05 or 07, it returns a null error :(

I did some reading and learned that javascript is able to 'catch' errors that are 'thrown' at it? My question now is that I'm wondering if there is an easy way to simply iterate to the next ID in line if this error is thrown.

Again, any and all help is appreciated, you guys are awesome.

**OLD DRAFT OF SCRIPT**

```
var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 3, max = getInputs.length; i < max; i++){
if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox' && i < 10){
 var count = i;
 var endid = count.toString();
 var begid = "shr_SUBJECT=VC0";
 var fullid = begid.concat(endid);
 document.getElementById(fullid).click();
 }
 else if(getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox' && i >= 10){
 var count = i ;
 var endid = count.toString();
 var begid = "shr_SUBJECT=VC";
 var fullid = begid.concat(endid);
 document.getElementById(fullid).click();
 }
 }
```

**--------EDIT#2----------**

An example of a table that I am trying to manipulate can be found at this URL:

http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?pid=ACS_12_5YR_DP02&prodType=table#

If you click on the 'Modify Table' button, you are able to select/deselect specific variables via the checkboxes. If you right-click on a couple of 'active' checkboxes and inspect the elements, and it looks something like this:

```
 <input id="shr_SUBJECT=VC03" checked="" alt="hide SUBJECT=VC03" name="" value="" onclick="javascript:hiderow('SUBJECT=VC03');" type="checkbox">


 <input id="shr_SUBJECT=VC25" checked="" alt="hide SUBJECT=VC25" name="" value="" onclick="javascript:hiderow('SUBJECT=VC25');" type="checkbox">
```

Thank you so much @Jonathan Steinbeck for the tip about the ternary operator, it really cleaned up my code.

The script works properly, but the problem I am running into now is that it doesn't iterate enough times after the try, catch statement. If there is a gap in the id #'s; say it jumps from shr_SUBJECT=VC19 to shr_SUBJECT=VC=24 the script will stop running. Is there a way to make it keep retrying the try/catch until it gets a valid ID # or one that exists/is an active checkbox?

**CURRENT DRAFT OF SCRIPT :**

```
var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 3, max = getInputs.length; i < max; i += 1) {
try {
    if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox'){
        document.getElementById("shr_SUBJECT=VC" + (i < 10 ? "0" : "") + i).click();
        }

    }   

catch (err) {
   i+=1;
   if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox'){
        if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox'){
        document.getElementById("shr_SUBJECT=VC" + (i < 10 ? "0" : "") + i).click();
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Check out [*dispatchEvent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) and MDN's [*Creating and triggering events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). Not sure about cross–browser support but it's getting better as browsers become more standardised. Oh, that error means that `document.getElementById('shr_SUBJECT=VC' + i)` is returning *null*, so an element with that ID doesn't exist in the document.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will research this some more

Answer (score 1):

When you call [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) with a non-existing ID, null is returned. Therefore this error means that you're trying to call the .click() method on null, which can't work.
So you should check what the correct ID naming scheme for the elements you want is. Maybe the elements' count starts with 1 instead of 0?

Also, the [.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) doesn't work for all elements like you would expect as far as I know. So depending on the kind of element you are trying to retrieve you might have to [create and dispatch your own event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) as suggested by RobG's comment.

**EDIT** in response to your recent edit:

You can wrap code that throws errors in a try-catch like this:

```
for (var i = 3, max = getInputs.length; i < max; i += 1) {
    try {
        document.getElementById("the_ID").click();
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        // continue stops the current execution of the loop body and continues
        // with the next iteration step
        continue;
    }
    // any code here will only be executed if there's not been an error thrown
    // in the try block because of the continue in the catch block
}
```

Also, what are you doing with the 'i' variable? It doesn't make sense to assign it to so many variables. This does the same:

```
document.getElementById("shr_SUBJECT=VC" + (i < 10 ? "0" : "") + i).click();
```

The `... ? ... : ...` is an operator (called the '[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)') that works like this: evaluate the expression before the "?" - if it results in a truthy value, the expression between "?" and ":" is evaluated and becomes the result of using the operator; if the condition results to false, the part after the ":" is evaluated as the value of the operator instead. So while "if" is a statement in JavaScript (and statements usually don't result in a value), the ternary operator can be used as an expression because it results in a value.

By concatenating a string with something else, you are forcing the 'something else' to be converted to string. So an expression like this will usually result in a string:

```
"" + someNonStringVar
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to define variables in a loop body in JavaScript. JavaScript variables have function scope, not block scope. What this means is that any variables defined in the loop body exist inside the whole function as well. Therefore it is recommended to write all of the "var"s at the top of your function to make it clear what their scope is. This behaviour of JavaScript is called '[hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)', by the way.

I've furthermore taken a look at the URL you've given in your recent edit but I fail to find the kind of naming scheme for IDs you describe. In which table did you find those?

**Edit** in response to your second edit:

You shouldn't mess with the 'i' variable inside the body of a for loop. It makes your code much harder to reason about and is probably not what you want to do anyway. You don't need to handle the next step of the iteration in the catch block. The 'i' variable is incremented even if there's an error during fetching the element from the DOM. That's why you use catch in the first place.

Comment: So upon further inspection,  

document.getElementById('shr_SUBJECT=VC03').click();  

yields the desired result, it clicks AND unchecks the box, is there anyway to have the for loop iterate each individual ID? the ID's look like this:  

shr_SUBJECT=VC03  

shr_SUBJECT=VC04  




shr_SUBJECT=VC05  

....  


shr_SUBJECT=VC11  


shr_SUBJECT=VC12



Apologies for the terrible formatting!

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate all your help, I got as far as I could again; not sure if you receive a notification on an 'edit' so I'm sending you a comment.